# BigQuery can't query large tables with lag

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table on BigQuery with 3,674,736 rows, when I run a query with the window function LAG and PARTITION BY a field that has 370 distinct values, BigQuery returns "Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.".

Is there any limit on window functions, but not documented?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lack of information to diagnose this.  However, based on the title it sounds like you may be trying to use window functions and allowLargeResults to generate output, [which is unsupported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults).

You may also want to review the [troubleshooting document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors) for more context on the resources exceeded error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I had done hundreds of queries successfully using lag or another window function on tables with more than 1 billion rows, extracting about 50 million rows and partitioning in fields with about 15,000 distinct values.
But, 50M/15k is less than 3.7M/370, so I suspect it depends on the size of the partition, because the calculation is an average, the partitions don't contain the same amount of elements.